# How to automatically copy file from EC2 to WordPress (backed by EC2)?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a WordPress Website backed by EC2. The expected workflow is like this:

- I upload a video to WordPress (which is backed by EC2).
- The video is accessible to EC2 instance and is processed by EC2.
- Then EC2 publishes the processed video onto WordPress.

The workflow involves the automatic file transfer between WordPress and EC2, as well as the mechanism to trigger the transfer/processing automatically.

Could anyone suggest how to realize it?

Comment: Could you add code that shows how you tried to solve the problem.

Comment: There is no code so far. I just follow the standard procedure to built a WordPress website from EC2 (https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/launch-a-wordpress-website/). I also added a file uploader plugin to WordPress and I can upload file now. The file is visible in WordPress.

Comment: Which step is causing you a problem? The upload, the "process" or the "publish"? Please provide more details of whichever step you are asking about.

Comment: @John, two steps caused me problems: (1) how to access the uploaded video using EC2 (I can only see it in WordPress console after I upload one)? (2) suppose I can access the video from EC2, how can I publish the resulting video to WordPress webpage after I process it using EC2? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the EC2 console, you need to figure out where WordPress is installed. On my instance (which is using AWS Linux 2), it's in /var/www/html. I know the Bitnami AMI's install WordPress somewhere else. [Here's a link to their configuration info.](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/wordpress/get-started/understand-config/)

Once you find the WP "root", look in wp-content/uploads. You'll see folders for years and months of when the files were uploaded. (For instance, I have a folder at /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/2019/06 that contains files uploaded in June 2019.) You can access the file from this location to process it.

When you are done, not only do you need to put the processed file in this location, but you'll need to update the Posts table to make WordPress aware of the file. [This should help.](https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/where-does-wordpress-store-images-on-your-site/)

[WordPress database documentation here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description)